# Errors: "Notice: Undefined index"

Tags: php, mysql

```
  [Errors][1]
```

I posted the code that I edited, and there are new errors w/c i didn't understand

> Notice: Undefined index: product_brand in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\JGMarketing\Admin_Area\insert_product.php on line 152
>
> Notice: Undefined index: product_price in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\JGMarketing\Admin_Area\insert_product.php on line 153
>
> Notice: Undefined index: product_images in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\JGMarketing\Admin_Area\insert_product.php on line 158
>
> Notice: Undefined index: product_images in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\JGMarketing\Admin_Area\insert_product.php on line 159

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<?php

include("includes/db.php");


?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inserting Product</title>


    <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>

</head> 
<body bgcolor="red">

<form action="insert_product.php"method="post"enctype= 
"multipart/form/data">
    <table align="center" width="700" border="5" bgcolor="white" >


    <tr>

        <td colspan="8"><h2 style="text-align:center;font-family:Arial;"> 
 Insert New Post Here</h2></td>

    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Name:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name= "product_name"  size="60" required />
 </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Category:</b></td>
        <td>

        <select name="product_cat" required>
            <option>Select Category</option>

            <?php

            global $con;
 $get_cat = "select * from categories";


 $run_cat = mysqli_query($con, $get_cat);

 while ($row_cat=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat)){

    $cat_id= $row_cat['cat_id'];
    $cat_title= $row_cat['cat_title'];

 echo "<li><option>$cat_title</option></li>";

 }          
            ?>
            </select>

        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Brand:</b></td>
        <td>

        <select name="product_brand" required>
            <option>Select Brand</option>

            <?php

            global $con;
 $get_brands = "select * from brands";


 $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);

 while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){

    $brands_id= $row_brands['brand_id'];
    $brands_title= $row_brands['brand_title'];

 echo "<li><option>$brands_title</option></li>";

 }

            ?>
            </select>





        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Image:</b></td>
        <td><input type="file" name= "product_image" required /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Price:</b></td>
        <td><input type="currency" name= "product_price" required/></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Description:</b></td>
        <td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name= "product_keywords" size="50" 
    required /></td>

    </tr>



<tr align="center">


<td colspan="7"><input type="Submit" name= "insert_post" value="Insert 
Product Here"/></td>

    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

 <?php


   if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){

//getting text data
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
$product_brands = $_POST['product_brand'];
$product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
$product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
$product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

//getting image data
$product_image = $_FILES['product_images']['name'];
$product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_images']['tmp_name'];

 move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"products_images/$product_image");

 $insert_product = "insert into products 

(product_cat,product_brands,product_name,product_price,product_desc,
 product_img,product_keyword) values ('$product_cat','$product_brands'
 ,'$product_name','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image'
 ,'$product_keywords')";

$run_product = mysqli_query($con,$insert_product);

if($run_product){

echo"<script>alert('Product Has been inserted')</script>";
echo"<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self')</script>";

 }  
 }




 ?>
```

Comment: what is the display error ??

Comment: It doesn't display anything. When I click the button,It loads but that just it after that it goes back in the table. When I refresh my db. theres no new entry.

Comment: One can only guess because not enough info is present. Do you know for certain that your post values are what you expect?

Comment: @Flor : use print_r or var_dump before send the database...do you have any idea use var_dump and print_r ?

Comment: Do you know if the script errors out? Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: i can see this line also some extra apostrophe...please check and do properly..    '$product_price',','$product_desc',

Answer (score 0):

You define your submit button name as "insert_post". But in if condition you take another name (if(isset($_POST['insert_product']))). Change the name.

Comment: tried it already. Still the same

Answer (score -1):

> Your Query IS wrong:

```
 $insert_product="insert into products 
(product_cat,product_brand,product_name,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) values('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_name','$product_price',','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";
```

> Insert This Query:

```
$insert_product="insert into products 
    (product_cat,product_brand,product_name,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) values('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_name','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";
```

Comment: tried it already. Still the same

Answer (score -1):

try use like this...please make sure check your db connection and form action properly.

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){

//getting text data from fields
 $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
$product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
$product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
$product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
$product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];


//getting image from fields
$product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
$product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");

    $insert_product="insert into products (product_cat,product_brand,product_name,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) values('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_name','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";

 $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

if($insert_pro){

echo"alert('Product Has been inserted')";

echo"window.open('insert_product.php','_self')";

}

else{
    echo "Something has gone wrong";
}

    }
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: product_brand in C:\xampp\htdocs\JGMarketing\Admin_Area\insert_product.php on line 153

Notice: Undefined index: product_price in C:\xampp\htdocs\JGMarketing\Admin_Area\insert_product.php on line 154

Notice: Undefined index: product_image in C:\xampp\htdocs\JGMarketing\Admin_Area\insert_product.php on line 160

Notice: Undefined index: product_image in C:\xampp\htdocs\JGMarketing\Admin_Area\insert_product.php on line 161 alert('Product Has beeninserted')window.open('insert_product.php','_self')

Comment: check your mysql table and check that field is there or not product_brand, product_price, product_image..then please use this line print_r($insert_product);exit(); between $insert_product="insert into products... and $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);..then put the results

Comment: when you put the total html form code, i can help..where your <form></form> ?

Comment: Im just starting making this website.  All I have is the insert_product,index and its db.

Comment: when you can put the full page...then i ll help...i can't see form tag..also db connection..